# Can i ask java to do something whenever a method of some class was called

Tags: java

i am new to java and was already surprised some times. so maybe this is possible in java?

I have classes

```
class X {
      string method_a(int x) {
         String str="abc";
         return str;
      }
}

class Y {
      void before(){};
      void after(){};
}
```

Can i tell Java to call methods "before" and "after" of class Y before or after "method_a" of class X is called?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). This isn't something which exists as part of "normal" Java, but there are various technologies around to enable it in various ways. You might want to start with [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't supported by the language itself, but can be provided by frameworks such as [Spring's Aspect Orriented Programming model](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes... you can.  It's called "aspects" (search for AspectJ).  I have found this Hello World example for you: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/AspectHelloWorldExample.htm

I have to warn you though, aspects works wonderfully well for logging and performance tracking, but can become a nightmare if used wrong.  As they say: "with great power comes great responsibility".